# Newtonsoft json serializer how lowercase the property

Tags: asp.net-core, json.net

I need display the property of json in lowercase the first word exmpple

```
{ name: ''}
```

but instead i get

```
{ Name: ''} <-- Error: uppercase
```

Im using:
.net core 3.1
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson 3.1.23

i write this

```
services.AddControllers()
            .AddNewtonsoftJson(opt =>
            {
                opt.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
                {
                    
                };
            })
            ;
```

not working

Answer (score 1):

I am always using this syntax

```
services.AddControllers()
.AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
  options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
        new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add below code in your `Startup.cs file`.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //...
    services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
    JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
    };
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

i found the problem is because im creating a dynamic object using Newtonsoft class

```
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject obj = new Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject();
            obj.Add(new Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty("Emp",item.Key.E));
            obj.Add(new Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty("Dep",item.Key.D));
            obj.Add(new Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty("Pu",item.Key.P));
```

and this json object are not convert to CamelCase and my dtos class yes